# What is the point of wrapping a generic in tuple [M] extends [never] in typescript

Tags: typescript

```
export type PayloadAction<
  P = void,
  T extends string = string,
  M = never,
  E = never
> = {
  payload: P
  type: T
} & ([M] extends [never]
  ? {}
  : {
      meta: M
    }) &
  ([E] extends [never]
    ? {}
    : {
        error: E
      })
```

This is the source code from 'redux-toolkit' , I don't know what is the meaning or [M] extends [never] , it looks wrap the type in tuple and then compare two tuples , why we do this?

The first time I thought this is syntax sugar , but after I remove the [], it does cause syntax bug;

```
export type PayloadAction<
  P = void,
  T extends string = string,
  M = never,
  E = never
> = {
  payload: P;
  type: T;
} & ( M extends never
  ? {}
  : {
      meta: M;
    }) &
  ([E] extends [never]
    ? {}
    : {
        error: E;
      });
```

```
// Example : Action with error
const errorAction: PayloadAction<void, 'FAILURE', never, string> = {
  payload: undefined,
  type: 'FAILURE',
  error: 'An error occurred',
};  // ! bug occurred ,    Type '{ payload: undefined; type: string; error: string; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

Comment: It removes distribution in conditional types. `never` is an empty union so it always evaluates to the false branch. You wrap with `[]` if you want to compare something to `never`.